# How to break $\ln(x+i \cdot y)$ into real and imaginary components?

Tags: complex-numbers

Wolfram shows that there are indeed Re and Im components without stating them: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=ln(x%2Bi*y)

How do I break $\ln(x+i \cdot y)$ into real and imaginary components?

Comment: The real part is $\ln(\sqrt{x^2+y^2})$. The imaginary part is the argument of $x+iy$, so the answer depends on how you specify it. There is an uncertainty that's an integer multiple of $2\pi i$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We want to express $x+iy$ as $re^{i\theta}$, for some value of $r$ and $\theta$.

First let's normalize $x+iy$ as $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}(\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}+\frac{y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}i)$.

We see that $r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ and we see that $\tan(\theta)=\frac{y}{x}$. Therefore, we have $\theta=\arctan(\frac{y}{x})$. We can then write $x+iy=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}e^{i\arctan(\frac{y}{x})}$. So we have:

$$\ln(x+iy)=\ln(\sqrt{x^2+y^2}e^{i\arctan(\frac{y}{x})})$$

$$\ln(x+iy)=\frac{1}{2}\ln(x^2+y^2)+i\arctan(\frac{y}{x})$$

Our real part is $\frac{1}{2}\ln(x^2+y^2)$ and our imaginary part is $i\arctan(\frac{y}{x})$.

Answer (score 2):

There are different ways to introduce a complex logarithm, but the definition which is used by WolframAlpha is

$$\ln(z) := \ln |z| + i \text{Arg} z$$

(see (8) [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/NaturalLogarithm.html)) where

$$\text{Arg} \, z = \arctan \left( \frac{y}{x} \right)$$

denotes the argument of $z=x+iy \in \mathbb{C}$ (see (2) [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ComplexArgument.html)). Hence,

$$\ln(x+iy) = \ln \sqrt{x^2+y^2} + i \arctan \left( \frac{y}{x} \right)$$

which implies

$$\text{Re} \, \ln(x+iy) = \ln \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$$

and

$$\text{Im} \, \ln(x+iy) = \arctan \left( \frac{y}{x} \right).$$